# how to handle a promise in firebase query when there is an if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I try to loop through all my documents and check if there is a matching between an object Id and my id then push the data into an array , my problem is that I can not get back any data my array is always empty here is my code :

```
   let d = []
   let b;
    const all = await db.collection('cars')
    .get()
       .then(documentSnapshot  => 
          {  if (!documentSnapshot.empty) {
              documentSnapshot.map(async (doc) => {
                         idd = await doc.data().user.id;
                         if(idd == 'myid'){
                           b = doc.data();
                           d.push(b) 
                       }
              
              });
          }
          }
          );

      return  Promise.all(all).then(() => setActiveSpinner(false), setThereIsData(true)).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

**EDIT:**

When I call getUsersList without await and then print the result, I get the following output

```
 const users = getUsersList(db);
  console.log('',users)
// Promise {status: "pending"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different issues within your implementation.

First, you are mixing both plain `Promise` objects with callback handlers along with `async/await` imperative usage which usually leads to un-wanted program behavior.

You are miss-collecting the different matching `document`s using the `Array.prototype.map` operator without neither returning a result for each element nor for the transformed result.

Here down a trimmed implementation using the `async/await` pattern:

```
const result = [];
const querySnapshots = await db.collection('cars').get();
for (const document of querySnapshots.docs) {
  const data = document.data();
  if (data.user.id === 'myid') {
    result.push(b);
  }
}
setActiveSpinner(false);
setThereIsData(true);
return result;
```

Comment: thanks @tmarwen your code fire an error  "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...document of documentSnapshots...')]"

Comment: Sorry for the typo missing the `get` call. Updated the answer.

Comment: thank you   @tmarwen , itw wroks now after also editing  const document of querySnapshots.docs